# Should an event object be named as a past tense verb or a noun?

Tags: events, naming-conventions, event-sourcing

I have been reading several event sourcing articles and examples. I have seem some as verbs, and others name as nouns with both of which might have event tacked on the end. Which is more correct? One example would be. OrderShippedEvent ( or sometimes just OrderShipped) vs ShipOrderEvent. The tense of the methods that operate on these types of objects have not helped much either. Here are some examples I've found.

```
process(OrderShippedEvent);
```

or

```
apply(ShipOrderEvent);
```

in other cases there will be handlers like

```
HandleOrderShipped(OrderShippedEvent)
```

or

```
HandleShipOrder(ShipOrderEvent)
```

I assume there should be a standard way to name and handle any type of events in any context, although I'm most interested in an Event Sourcing scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An event usually defines something *has happened* or *has been triggered* and sends a message *after* being triggered. I valiantly stand besides the option to keep it with a past-tense verb in the middle. Of course some languages have specific best practices for naming conventions - some have onEventName, some use the action happening now (Button.Click). As for appending the Event word on the name, well, I'm not used to it - but as far as I am aware, naming conventions *exist to get rid of **magical** variables* (where by looking at them you can't grasp the least of what its data is or why it even exists), so the same would apply for methods and events - like a method named DoSomething() and an Event named Thing. One can understand them but that requires a more adventurous soul to go and parse the code to properly place the *super-well-named* variable/method/function in some human-understandable flow.

Answer (score 6):

Well, they mean different things:

- **ShipOrderEvent** means that a an order is about to be shipped, but we have no certainty as whether it has or hasn't been shipped yet.
- **OrderShippedEvent** means that the order has been shipped, for sure.

They are smilar to the FormClosing/FormClosed events of the System.Windows.Forms.Form class in .NET. So, rather than suggesting what name to use, I'd rather suggest that you think what you want to represent by your event, and name it accordingly.